# How do I create a View filter by a parent taxonomy term?

Tags: 7, views

I've got a taxonomy that is set up as such, which I am using with Taxonomy Term Templates:

`Manufacturer>>Model>>Colour`

Eg:

`Honda>>Accord>>Red`

I'd like to create a View that displays all siblings of a Taxonomy, eg if I am on the Accord page I'd like the view to return other Honda models (eg: Civic, CR-X, HR-V, Odyssey).

I've tried using the `%term:parent` as a contextual filter, but have had no luck - no results display.

Would anyone know how I might go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow such steps for getting your result (Child Items)

1)Add Taxonomy term: Term ID in CONTEXTUAL FILTERS.
2)Add Taxonomy term: Parent term in RELATIONSHIPS. (leave Require this relationship unchecked.)
3)Add Taxonomy term: Parent term in filter section. select great than 0.
4)Do not forget to filter your taxnonmy term in mycase Taxonomy vocabulary: Machine name (= airports).
5)Add Taxonomy term: Rendered Taxonomy term to your fields , select relationship to parent , check the Exclude from display.
6)In setting, under FORMAT section. In grouping field 1, select (Parent) Taxonomy term: Rendered Taxonomy term.

You should good to go. you can use view tpl to add more class base on the group.
 I have enclose my screenshot for references. [image]

Comment: Any idea how to exclude the current term? ('Accord' in my example above)

Comment: Yea Melting , According your example if you want to show other related honda model and your URL is car/%/model then please follow such steps :
1. In contextual filter choose "(term) Taxonomy term: Term ID"

Comment: Yea Melting , According your example if you want to show other related honda model and your URL is car/%/model then please follow such steps :
1. In contextual filter choose "(term) Taxonomy term: Term ID"  
2. Provide default value and set "Raw value from URL".  
3. select path component is "2" or you can set aacording URL % sign
4. In validation critria select "specific validation critria"
5. Check yout taxonomy there